# ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis: input_shape=[(None, 512, 2, 2), (None, 256, 1, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

The Code was working previously in Keras 1.2 version and wanted to update this to version Keras 2.9

```
    def compile(self):

        K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

        inputs = Input(shape=self.config['input_shape'])

        conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(inputs)
        conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
        conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv1)
        conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv1)

        conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(pool1)
        conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
        conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv2)
        conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
        pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv2)

        conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(pool2)
        conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
        conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv3)
        conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
        conv3 = Dropout(0.5)(conv3)
        pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv3)

        conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(pool3)
        conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
        conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv4)
        conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
        conv4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
        pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv4)

        conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(pool4)
        conv5 = Activation('relu')(conv5)
        conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv5)
        conv5 = Activation('relu')(conv5)
        conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

        up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4],
                    mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
        conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(up6)
        conv6 = Activation('relu')(conv6)
        conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv6)
        conv6 = Activation('relu')(conv6)
        conv6 = Dropout(0.5)(conv6)

        up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3],
                    mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
        conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(up7)
        conv7 = Activation('relu')(conv7)
        conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv7)
        conv7 = Activation('relu')(conv7)

        up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2],
                    mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
        conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(up8)
        conv8 = Activation('relu')(conv8)
        conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv8)
        conv8 = Activation('relu')(conv8)

        up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1],
                    mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
        conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(up9)
        conv9 = Activation('relu')(conv9)
        conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal')(conv9)
        conv9 = Activation('relu')(conv9)

        # Softmax Activation setup begin.
        conv10 = Convolution2D(2, 1, 1)(conv9)

        output = Flatten()(conv10)
        H, W, D = self.config['output_shape_onehot']
        output = Reshape((H * W, D))(output)
        output = Activation('softmax')(output)
        output = Reshape(self.config['output_shape_onehot'])(output)  # 128 x 128 x 2

        # TODO: consider not doing this... maybe it makes a difference in how the loss function works.
        # Slicing off the softmax probability of having a positive sample.
        # This allows you to use the regular keras metrics and avoid all the
        # np.argmax() calls.
        def probability_positive(onehot):
            return onehot[:, :, :, 1]
        output = Lambda(probability_positive)(output)
        output = Reshape(self.config['output_shape'])(output)

        def weighted_log_loss(yt, yp):
            # Log loss weighs boundary errors more heavily to encourage clean boundaries.
            # This is similar to UNet paper.
            a = yt * K.log(yp + K.epsilon())
            b = (1 - yt) * K.log(1 + K.epsilon() - yp)
            m = 5
            # [0,1] -> [-1,0] -> [1,0] -> [m-1,0] -> [m,1]
            w = ((yt - 1) * -1) * (m - 1) + 1
            return -1 * K.mean(w * (a + b))
            # Below return statement would match the keras binary_crossentropy value.
            # return -1. * K.mean((a + b))

        self.net = Model(input=inputs, output=output)
        self.net.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005),
                         # loss='binary_crossentropy',
                         loss=weighted_log_loss,
                         metrics=['fmeasure', 'precision', 'recall', dice_coef, jaccard_coef, jaccard_coef_int])

        return
```

Tried updating to Keras 2.x version but giving errors while concatenating as I converted merge to concatenate

ERROR: ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 512, 2, 2), (None, 256, 1, 1)]

```
def compile(self):

        K.tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

        inputs = Input(shape=self.config['input_shape'])
        #initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()
        conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
        conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
        conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
        conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', strides=(2, 2))(conv1)

        conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
        conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
        conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
        conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
        pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', strides=(2, 2))(conv2)

        conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
        conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
        conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
        conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
        conv3 = Dropout(0.5)(conv3)
        pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same',strides=(2, 2))(conv3)

        conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
        conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
        conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
        conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
        conv4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
        pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', strides=(2, 2))(conv4)

        conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
        conv5 = Activation('relu')(conv5)
        conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
        conv5 = Activation('relu')(conv5)
        conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

        up6 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4],
                    axis=3)
        conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up6)
        conv6 = Activation('relu')(conv6)
        conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)
        conv6 = Activation('relu')(conv6)
        conv6 = Dropout(0.5)(conv6)

        up7 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3],
                    axis=3)
        conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up7)
        conv7 = Activation('relu')(conv7)
        conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', init='he_normal')(conv7)
        conv7 = Activation('relu')(conv7)

        up8 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2],
                    axis=3)
        conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up8)
        conv8 = Activation('relu')(conv8)
        conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)
        conv8 = Activation('relu')(conv8)

        up9 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1],
                   axis=3)
        conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up9)
        conv9 = Activation('relu')(conv9)
        conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
        conv9 = Activation('relu')(conv9)
        
        # Softmax Activation setup begin.
        conv10 = Convolution2D(2, 1, 1)(conv9)

        output = Flatten()(conv10)
        H, W, D = self.config['output_shape_onehot']
        output = Reshape((H * W, D))(output)
        output = Activation('softmax')(output)
        output = Reshape(self.config['output_shape_onehot'])(output)  # 128 x 128 x 2

        # TODO: consider not doing this... maybe it makes a difference in how the loss function works.
        # Slicing off the softmax probability of having a positive sample.
        # This allows you to use the regular keras metrics and avoid all the
        # np.argmax() calls.
        def probability_positive(onehot):
            return onehot[:, :, :, 1]
        output = Lambda(probability_positive)(output)
        output = Reshape(self.config['output_shape'])(output)

        def weighted_log_loss(yt, yp):
            # Log loss weighs boundary errors more heavily to encourage clean boundaries.
            # This is similar to UNet paper.
            a = yt * K.log(yp + K.epsilon())
            b = (1 - yt) * K.log(1 + K.epsilon() - yp)
            m = 5
            # [0,1] -> [-1,0] -> [1,0] -> [m-1,0] -> [m,1]
            w = ((yt - 1) * -1) * (m - 1) + 1
            return -1 * K.mean(w * (a + b))
            # Below return statement would match the keras binary_crossentropy value.
            # return -1. * K.mean((a + b))

        self.net = Model(input=inputs, output=output)
        self.net.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005),
                         # loss='binary_crossentropy',
                         loss=weighted_log_loss,
                         metrics=['fmeasure', 'precision', 'recall', dice_coef, jaccard_coef, jaccard_coef_int])

        return

Need you help guys? Could you pls me convert this?
```

Comment: Tried axis= -1 still the same

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: None of your axes match. Check your error message. If you flattened them or used 1D arrays, you can concatenate easier. Currently, you have two 3D inputs of shape (512, 2, 2) and (256, 1, 1). You can't horizontally nor vertically concatenate those on any axis. If you don't think it will affect your data, you can try stacking the second input on itself, then you'd have three matching axes to pick from.